# Swagger node is taking URL phrase as parameter

Tags: node.js, rest, swagger, swagger-node-express

I'm using [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) for REST APIs and I've found an absurd issue here.

Here's my one of GET requests:

```
GET: /students/{id}/{name}
```

(id is number)

And now I wrote another request:

```
GET: /students/routeInfo/{id}
```

But the **2**nd request me following error:

**Expected type is number, found type string**. Which clearly means **2**nd request is trying to "mask" **1**st request. Which I think shouldn't be.

Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

In your path definitions, changeChange your 'parameters' `type: number` for `type: string`

Your path will look like this:

```
/students/routeInfo/{id}:
x-swagger-router-controller: yourStudentController
get:
  tags: 
    - Student
  description: description
  operationId: yourOperation
  parameters:
    - name: id
      in: path
      description: description id of routeInfo 
      required: true
      type: string
```

See more at https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/

Comment: Please remove or edit your answer. You need to learn more about swagger and `type` keyword. This won't solve the problem. You clearly didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same situation is described in the OpenAPI specification v3.0 document: section Path Templating Matching, 3rd example. It is called ambiguous matching, and "... it's up to the tooling to decide which path to use."  The tool, of course, being swagger-node.

It is weird though,  isn't it!